# dimension error with scipy optimize.minimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to minimise the objective function: objective_function_2() subject to the inequality constraints 69 < T(x) < 71. The objective of the optimisation is to find the set of Fourier series parameters [c0, c1, c2, wavelength] that minimises the objective function (curve fitting problem). fx() is the function that calculates the residuals between the data and the estimated values of the Fourier series. T(x) is the function calculate_tightness() that calculates the range of the fourier series estimated at each iteration.

The problem is that I don't understand why I get this error message: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)

the objective_function_2() produce an n-vector of residuals and calculate_tightness() one scalar value.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint, NonlinearConstraint, BFGS, minimize

ref_fld = np.array([-479.9024323 , -469.80142114, -459.70040999, -449.59939883,
       -439.49838768, -429.39737652, -419.29636536, -409.19535421,
       -399.09434305, -388.9933319 , -378.89232074, -368.79130958,
       -358.69029843, -348.58928727, -338.48827611, -328.38726496,
       -318.2862538 , -308.18524265, -298.08423149, -287.98322033,
       -277.88220918, -267.78119802, -257.68018686, -247.57917571,
       -237.47816455, -227.3771534 , -217.27614224, -207.17513108,
       -197.07411993, -186.97310877, -176.87209762, -166.77108646,
       -156.6700753 , -146.56906415, -136.46805299, -126.36704183,
       -116.26603068, -106.16501952,  -96.06400837,  -85.96299721,
        -75.86198605,  -65.7609749 ,  -55.65996374,  -45.55895258,
        -35.45794143,  -25.35693027,  -15.25591912,   -5.15490796,
          4.9461032 ,   15.04711435,   25.14812551,   35.24913667,
         45.35014782,   55.45115898,   65.55217013,   75.65318129,
         85.75419245,   95.8552036 ,  105.95621476,  116.05722591,
        126.15823707,  136.25924823,  146.36025938,  156.46127054,
        166.5622817 ,  176.66329285,  186.76430401,  196.86531516,
        206.96632632,  217.06733748,  227.16834863,  237.26935979,
        247.37037095,  257.4713821 ,  267.57239326,  277.67340441,
        287.77441557,  297.87542673,  307.97643788,  318.07744904,
        328.1784602 ,  338.27947135,  348.38048251,  358.48149366,
        368.58250482,  378.68351598,  388.78452713,  398.88553829,
        408.98654944,  419.0875606 ,  429.18857176,  439.28958291,
        449.39059407,  459.49160523,  469.59261638,  479.69362754,
        489.79463869,  499.89564985,  509.99666101,  520.09767216])
fld = np.array([-300.41522506, -120.9280477 , -274.77413647,  494.45656622,
        -44.00495929, -479.90233432,   58.55913797, -326.056248  ,
         84.20018256,  443.17449743])
flr = np.array([-13.20752855,  38.56985419,  44.28484794, -51.64708478,
       -10.50558888, -49.95878419, -53.88137785, -12.73304144,
       -54.2792669 ,  -7.59544309])

def fourier_series(x, c0, c1, c2, w):
    """

    Parameters
    ----------
    x
    c0
    c1
    c2
    w

    Returns
    -------

    """
    v = np.array(x.astype(float))
    # v.fill(c0)
    v = c0 + c1 * np.cos(2 * np.pi / w * x) + c2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi / w * x)
    return np.rad2deg(np.arctan(v))

def calculate_splot(ref_fold_frame, popt):
    
    return np.rad2deg(np.arctan(fourier_series(ref_fold_frame, *popt)))

def calculate_tightness(theta): 
    
    curve = calculate_splot(ref_fld, theta)
    amax = np.arctan(np.deg2rad(curve.max()))
    amin = np.arctan(np.deg2rad(curve.min()))
    
    return 180 - np.rad2deg(2*np.tan((amax - amin) / 2))

def fx(theta, x, y):
    # function to calculate residuals for optimisation (least squares)
    return np.tan(np.deg2rad(y)) - fourier_series(x, *theta) 

def objective_function_2(theta):
    x = fld
    y = flr
    
    return  fx(theta, x, y) + calculate_tightness(theta)

Cx = NonlinearConstraint(calculate_tightness, 69, 71, jac='2-point', hess=BFGS()) 
x0 = [0, 1, 1, 500]
res = minimize(objective_function_2, x0, constraints=[Cx], method='trust-constr', 

               options={'verbose': 1}, )
```

#### Error message

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_91/1210121354.py in <module>
      1 Cx = NonlinearConstraint(calculate_tightness, 69, 71, jac='2-point', hess=BFGS()) #setup_optimisation_constraints(constraints_matrix, [60, -1e-2], [71, 1e-4], linear=False)
      2 x0 = theta[recovery<1][0]
----> 3 res = minimize(objective_function_2, x0, constraints=[Cx], method='trust-constr', 
      4 
      5                options={'verbose': 1}, )

/mnt/c/Users/rcha0044/LoopPhD/LOOP_ENV/env_18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    632                                constraints, callback=callback, **options)
    633     elif meth == 'trust-constr':
--> 634         return _minimize_trustregion_constr(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp,
    635                                             bounds, constraints,
    636                                             callback=callback, **options)

/mnt/c/Users/rcha0044/LoopPhD/LOOP_ENV/env_18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/minimize_trustregion_constr.py in _minimize_trustregion_constr(fun, x0, args, grad, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, xtol, gtol, barrier_tol, sparse_jacobian, callback, maxiter, verbose, finite_diff_rel_step, initial_constr_penalty, initial_tr_radius, initial_barrier_parameter, initial_barrier_tolerance, factorization_method, disp)
    507 
    508     elif method == 'tr_interior_point':
--> 509         _, result = tr_interior_point(
    510             objective.fun, objective.grad, lagrangian_hess,
    511             n_vars, canonical.n_ineq, canonical.n_eq,

/mnt/c/Users/rcha0044/LoopPhD/LOOP_ENV/env_18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/tr_interior_point.py in tr_interior_point(fun, grad, lagr_hess, n_vars, n_ineq, n_eq, constr, jac, x0, fun0, grad0, constr_ineq0, jac_ineq0, constr_eq0, jac_eq0, stop_criteria, enforce_feasibility, xtol, state, initial_barrier_parameter, initial_tolerance, initial_penalty, initial_trust_radius, factorization_method)
    302     s0 = np.maximum(-1.5*constr_ineq0, np.ones(n_ineq))
    303     # Define barrier subproblem
--> 304     subprob = BarrierSubproblem(
    305         x0, s0, fun, grad, lagr_hess, n_vars, n_ineq, n_eq, constr, jac,
    306         barrier_parameter, tolerance, enforce_feasibility,

/mnt/c/Users/rcha0044/LoopPhD/LOOP_ENV/env_18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/tr_interior_point.py in __init__(self, x0, s0, fun, grad, lagr_hess, n_vars, n_ineq, n_eq, constr, jac, barrier_parameter, tolerance, enforce_feasibility, global_stop_criteria, xtol, fun0, grad0, constr_ineq0, jac_ineq0, constr_eq0, jac_eq0)
     51         self.xtol = xtol
     52         self.fun0 = self._compute_function(fun0, constr_ineq0, s0)
---> 53         self.grad0 = self._compute_gradient(grad0)
     54         self.constr0 = self._compute_constr(constr_ineq0, constr_eq0, s0)
     55         self.jac0 = self._compute_jacobian(jac_eq0, jac_ineq0, s0)

/mnt/c/Users/rcha0044/LoopPhD/LOOP_ENV/env_18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/tr_interior_point.py in _compute_gradient(self, g)
    137 
    138     def _compute_gradient(self, g):
--> 139         return np.hstack((g, -self.barrier_parameter*np.ones(self.n_ineq)))
    140 
    141     def _compute_jacobian(self, J_eq, J_ineq, s):

<__array_function__ internals> in hstack(*args, **kwargs)

/mnt/c/Users/rcha0044/LoopPhD/LOOP_ENV/env_18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in hstack(tup)
    343         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    344     else:
--> 345         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
    346 
    347 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

#### SciPy/NumPy/Python version information

1.7.1 1.21.3 sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: Hi Rabii, it's hard to understand your code without the import statements, for example the `minimize` function appears undefined. Please augment your code sample

Comment: `fld`, `flr` and `ref_fld` are not defined in your code, and they determine the size of the arrays in the optimization. If you don't provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to guess where the problem is.

Comment: @aerobiomat Sorry I added the variables

Comment: scipy.optimize.minimize is for minimizing a **scalar** function. Thus, your objective function should return a scalar, not a vector. If you really want to minimize your current objective function, you should take a look at *multi-criteria optimization* and the principle of a *pareto optimality*.